# loading stylesheet twice with preload

Tags: html, css, preload

I preload the stylesheet like this.
`<link rel="preload" href="public/style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">`
Since preload is not supported in all browser, I add follwing at end of body
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/style.css>`

This will load the stylesheet twice. Is there a way to do it better? That is, without making the browser re-parse the stylesheet?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to unchecked the **disable cache** while testing in the chrome dev tool. Otherwise, it will not use already preloaded cached links.

**With disabled cache:**

[image]

**Without disabled cache:**
[image]

Comment: Just because it is not loading a second time, does that mean it will not be parsed also? I feel it will. Let me know.